# Nested if in Gnu Mathprog for an energy model

Tags: gnu, glpk, mathprog

I have a code in Gnu Mathprog for an energy model:

```
s.t.EBa1_RateOfFuelProduction1{r in REGION, l in TIMESLICE, f in FUEL, t in TECHNOLOGY, m in MODE_OF_OPERATION, y in YEAR: OutputActivityRatio[r,t,f,m,y] <> 0}:
RateOfActivity[r,l,t,m,y]*OutputActivityRatio[r,t,f,m,y]  = RateOfProductionByTechnologyByMode[r,l,t,m,f,y];

s.t.EBa4_RateOfFuelUse1{r in REGION, l in TIMESLICE, f in FUEL, t in TECHNOLOGY, m in MODE_OF_OPERATION, y in YEAR: InputActivityRatio[r,t,f,m,y]<>0}:
RateOfActivity[r,l,t,m,y]*InputActivityRatio[r,t,f,m,y]  = RateOfUseByTechnologyByMode[r,l,t,m,f,y];
```

I want to put these two constraints in one, and i am thinking to insert two conditional expressions(if).The first if, will be referred to technology(t) and fuel(f)where the OutputActivityRatio<>0 and the second one for the same technology(t) it will start checking again the f(fuels) to see if the InputActivityRatio<>0. 
Like that:

```
s.t.RateOfProduction{r in REGION, l in TIMESLICE, f in FUEL, t in TECHNOLOGY, m in MODE_OF_OPERATION, y in YEAR: OutputActivityRatio[r,t,f,m,y]     <>0}:
  RateOfActivity[r,l,t,m,y]*OutputActivityRatio[r,t,f,m,y]  = RateOfProductionByTechnologyByMode[r,l,t,m,f,y]
  If InputActivityRatio[r,t,ff,m,y]<>0 then 
     RateOfActivity[r,l,t,m,y]*InputActivityRatio[r,t,f,m,y]  = RateOfUseByTechnologyByMode[r,l,t,m,f,y]
  else 0
else 0 ;
```

My question is: is it possible to have two if in series (nested if) and between them to have an equation as well?How can I write something like that?
Thank you very much!

Comment: Please elaborate your question and also format your code properly.

Comment: Sorry,my mistake!I format it.

Answer (score 0):

As described in your other Question (regarding nested if-then-else in mathprog) there are no If-Then-Else statements in mathprog. The workaround with conditional for-loops is also no solution for your problem, since you can only use them in pre- or post processing of your data (you can't use this in your constraints!).

But there are still possibilities to merge your constraints. I think something like the following would work, if your condition is that either Input or Output is 0.

```
s.t.RateOfProduction{r in REGION, l in TIMESLICE, f in FUEL, t in TECHNOLOGY, m in MODE_OF_OPERATION, y in YEAR}:
(RateOfActivity[r,l,t,m,y]*OutputActivityRatio[r,t,f,m,y])
+ (RateOfActivity[r,l,t,m,y]*InputActivityRatio[r,t,f,m,y])  
= RateOfProductionByTechnologyByMode[r,l,t,m,f,y];
```

Here in the lefthandside summation one multiplication would turn zero. 
Since I don't know which parts are variables and which a parameters, this solution could also fail (for example it could be problematic if there is input and output at the same time and the rest of the model doesn't contain the right bounds for that)